# Error: Main method not found in class Example_Applet,

Tags: java, html, applet

The Full Error Message:

[ Main method not found in class Example_Applet, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args) ]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Example_Applet extends Applet {

    String message;

    public void init() {
        message="My first Java Applet";
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawString(message, 50, 60 );
    }
}
```

I was trying to replicate my textbooks example applet code. When I try to execute the code in Notebook++ it just prints the code in the browser. Even though it compiles without the errors in JCreator I get the aforementioned error message.Really be huge help if someone could help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Applets runs in different way than ordinary java applications.
While latter should have `public static void main(Strin[] args)` method and run with `java` command the former can be run locally with `appletviewer` command (bundled with your JDK).
In order to run applet locally you should create HTML file with `<applet>` tag inside. Something like this:

```
<applet code="Example_Applet.class" width="300" height="300">
  This text will be shown in browsers without java applets support.
</applet>
```

Place it in same directory as your class `Example_Applet.class` file (compiled form your `Example_applet.java`) and then run it with `appletviewer YourHtmlFileName.html` command.

Future reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html

**FYI:** Applets is quite outdated technology and will not work in most of current browsers. 
So I suggest you to find not so old textbook as your one.

Comment: Plus one for the **FYI** - See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).